# How to solve the 'A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.'

Tags: flutter, dart

I use `Dismissible()` for deleting notifications. The notification is deleted. but shows red color screen error that says
**A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.**........... I can see similar post answers that say to use `UniqueKey()`. In my case, it does not work.is there any methode to do it?

here is my code.

```
class NotificationsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotificationsPage({super.key});

  @override
  _NotificationsPageState createState() => _NotificationsPageState();
}

class _NotificationsPageState extends State<NotificationsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cP = Provider.of<CommonProvider>(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Notifications'),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.h),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder<List<Notifications>?>(
                  future: cP.getNotifications(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final notifications = snapshot.data;

                      return SizedBox(
                        height: 500.h,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: notifications?.length ?? 0,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final notification = notifications![index];

                            return Dismissible(
                              key: Key(notification.id.toString()),
                              onDismissed: (direction) {
                                deleteNotification(notification.id.toString());
                              },
                              child: Card(
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(notification.title!),
                                  subtitle: Text(notification.subTitle!),
                                  leading: CustomImageFrame(
                                      icon: notification.icon!),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                    } else {
                      return Center(
                          child: CustomText(text: 'No Notification Available'));
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    delete();
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                ))
              ],
            ),
          )
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

deleteNotification.

````
Future<void> deleteNotification(String id) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  // Step 1: Retrieve the list from SharedPreferences
  String notificationsString = prefs.getString('notifications') ?? '[]';
  List<Notifications> notificationsList =
      (json.decode(notificationsString) as List)
          .map((item) => Notifications.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

  // Step 2: Find the index of the item with the specified id
  int indexToDelete =
      notificationsList.indexWhere((notification) => notification.id == id);

  // Step 3: Remove the item at that index
  if (indexToDelete != -1) {
    notificationsList.removeAt(indexToDelete);

    // Step 4: Save the updated list back to SharedPreferences
    String updatedNotificationsString = json.encode(notificationsList);
    prefs.setString('notifications', updatedNotificationsString);
  }
}```
````

Comment: How does `deleteNotification` look like?

Comment: updated the code. Pls look

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the widget tree when widget gets dismissed.

Use setstate to rebuild the widget tree. This will update widget tree and remove a Dismissible widget.

```
return Dismissible(
 key: Key(notification.id.toString()),
 onDismissed: (direction) {
   deleteNotification(notification.id.toString()).then((_) {
     setState(() {});
   });
 },
 child: Card(
   child: ListTile(
     title: Text(notification.title!),
     subtitle: Text(notification.subTitle!),
     leading: CustomImageFrame(
         icon: notification.icon!),
   ),
 ),
);
```

Comment: Tried. does not work.

Comment: add this in setstate  setState(() {
      notifications!.removeAt(index);
    });

Comment: no.it also does not work.still,the error is exist brother